# Modify global variable in a function and display it in tkinter(edited)

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from threading import Thread
import PIL.Image
import win32.lib.win32con as win32con
import winsound, ctypes, time, os, win32gui
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from datetime import datetime


desktopPath = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ["USERPROFILE"]),"Desktop")
Image1 = PIL.Image.open(r"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper.jpg")
Image1Copy = Image1.copy()
copyPath = "\\Program\\Files\\OriginalBackground\\backgroundCopy.jpg"
Image1Copy.save(r""+desktopPath+copyPath)
Minimize = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(Minimize, win32con.SW_MINIMIZE)
i = 1
message = "Hello"

def changePhoto():
    global i
    while(1):
        if(i == 17):
            i = 1
        s = str(i)
        path = desktopPath+"\\Program\\Files\\Images\\Cheloo"+s+".jpg"
        ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, path, 0)
        i = i+1
        time.sleep(5)
def playSound():
    while(1):
        winsound.PlaySound(desktopPath+"\\Program\\Files\\Sound\\Dua Lipa - Levitating Featuring DaBaby (Official Music Video).wav" , winsound.SND_FILENAME)

def displayScreen():
    window = Tk()
    window.geometry("1920x1080")
    canvas = Canvas(window, width = 1920, height = 1080)
    canvas.configure()
    canvas.pack()
    global message
    firstChar = message[0]
    message = message[1:]+firstChar
    label = Label(window, text = message, font=("Arial", 25))
    label.place(x = 540,y = 0)
    window.mainloop()

#Thread(target = changePhoto).start()
#Thread(target = playSound).start()
displayScreen()
```

I want this code to open a window and print message something like this:

Hello
elloH
lloHe
loHel
oHell
Hello
.....
.....

But the program just display the initial message "Hello" and that's it

What should I do ? what should I change ?

Comment: Well, you never modify `message = "Hello"` or `label.text`. What function do you want to run that should modify it?

Comment: DON'T run TkInter in a child thread.  Your GUI should always be in the main thread.  There are exceptions, but they are rare.

Comment: The displayScreen() should modify my messages, actually just the 3 lines starting from global messages should do it. I tried put the contain of the function inside a while infinte loop(while True:) and it's kinda work, but I have to continuously close the window to make the message to change in the way I want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way using class. I guess it can be done without class too.
Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from datetime import datetime

class Text:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
        self.message = "  Dua Lipa - Levitating Featuring DaBaby (Official Music Video)  "
        self.w = self.window.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.h = self.window.winfo_screenheight()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.window, width = self.w, height = self.h)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.new_canvas = self.canvas.create_text(600, 220, text = self.message, font=("Purisa",20))
    def updateText(self):
        self.message = self.message[-1] + self.message[:-1]
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.new_canvas, text = self.message)
        self.window.after(200, self.updateText)
    def start(self):
        self.updateText()
        self.window.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = Text()
    t.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can display multiple versions of the message by keeping track of an output variable (`output` in the below code) that has these versions of the message appended as a single string separated by a newline character. Afterwards, you can display the output variable as tkinter label instead of message

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from datetime import datetime

def displayScreen():
    window = Tk()
    window.geometry("1920x1080")
    canvas = Canvas(window, width = 1920, height = 1080)
    canvas.configure()
    canvas.pack()

    message = 'Hello'
    output = message
    for i in range(len(message) - 1):
        firstChar = message[0]
        message = message[1:] + firstChar
        output += '\n' + message

    label = Label(window, text = output, font=("Arial", 25))
    label.place(x = 540,y = 0)
    window.mainloop()

displayScreen()
```